# Does ros::Duration::sleep spin?

Tags: ros, spin, sleep, time, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I do ros::Duration::sleep does ros spin and are callback functions called?

If not is there a way to pause the program while still managing callbacks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203760/does-ros::duration::sleep-spin?/) by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> If I do ros::Duration::sleep does ros spin and are callback functions called?

No. Sleep just sleeps the thread for the specified duration.

> If not is there a way to pause the program while still managing callbacks?

You can have a loop that alternates sleeping and spinning, as exemplified in [this roscpp tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.CA-2f0de5afcea33b164ff81dfbdb2ca623dfa24042_82), or you can have separate spinner threads. I recommend reading the ROS wiki page on [callbacks and spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2015-03-02**:
If your question is answered, could you post, for the record, which approached you ended up using?.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2019-03-14**:
So if I have an image callback and a service callback and do sleep in the service callback, will the image callback be blocked too?

**Comment by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on 2019-10-07**:
@Mehdi: With the standard single-threaded ros::spin: yes